# Using Registry to Set Default Printer VBA ONLY When Printer is Active

Tags: excel, vba, function, printing

I use Leith Ross' VBA code to cycle through printers on my machine/network, and select the printer that matches the parameters I pass as the default printer. See below:

```
Function FindPrinter(ByVal PrinterName As String) As String

  Dim Arr As Variant
  Dim Device As Variant
  Dim Devices As Variant
  Dim Printer As String
  Dim RegObj As Object
  Dim RegValue As String
  Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

  Set RegObj = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
  RegObj.enumvalues HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices", Devices, Arr

  For Each Device In Devices
    RegObj.getstringvalue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices", Device, RegValue
    Printer = Device & " on " & Split(RegValue, ",")(1)
    If InStr(1, Printer, PrinterName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
       FindPrinter = Printer
       Exit Function
     End If
  Next


End Function
```

This gets slightly more complicated, because IT sometimes names the printers slightly different names. Still, the function I use finds the printer I am looking for and sets it to the default printer.

The real problem sets when some computers that use this code have duplicate drivers/software of the printers on them, and only one of them is online while the rest are offline. I usually have to get someone from IT to uninstall the offline drivers, or else this function sometimes grabs the offline drivers and the code doesn't work. Instead of having to rely on them to do this, I was interested in modifying this function to only set the active printer to whatever criteria I pass it to ONLY if the printer that matches the `Instr` criteria in the function is active.

Is there anything in VBA, and/or anything I can add to this code to check if the printer that matches the `Instr` criteria is actually online, and if it is THEN `FindPrinter = Printer` `Exit Function`? My online search results haven't really been helpful; almost everything just either gives this function or some other function to display/set default printer.

EDIT: Just to note, not really looking for a handout answer, although if you provide exactly how to do it then I'd be grateful. If you are more so inclined to link me to documentation on where I can find the answer/solution, I'd be more than happy to do the research.

Comment: Would this help? http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/VB_Script/Q_26661678.html

Comment: http://www.merrioncomputing.com/Programming/PrintStatus.htm

Comment: @SeanC That is what I was looking for. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this would be a link only answer otherwise, I post the relevant text below...

---

Unashamedly stolen from http://www.merrioncomputing.com/Programming/PrintStatus.htm

---

Getting the status of the selected printer from Visual Basic
What the Printer object missed

Printing has long been a very problematic part of developing complete and professional applications in Visual Basic. This was redressed to a large degree with the new Printer object introduced in Visual Basic 4.

There are, however, shortcomings with this object. The biggest shortcoming is that you cannot find out whether the printer is ready, busy, out of paper etc. from your application.

Fortunately there is an API call, GetPrinter which returns a great deal more information about a printer.

```
Private Declare Function GetPrinterApi Lib "winspool.drv" Alias _
       "GetPrinterA" (ByVal hPrinter As Long, _
         ByVal Level As Long, _
         buffer As Long, _
         ByVal pbSize As Long, _
         pbSizeNeeded As Long) As Long
```

This takes the handle to a printer in hPrinter and fills the buffer provided to it with information from the printer driver. To get the handle from the Printer object, you need to use the OpenPrinter API call.
 This handle must be released using the ClosePrinter API call as soon as you are finished with it.

```
Private Type PRINTER_DEFAULTS
  pDatatype As String
  pDevMode As DEVMODE
  DesiredAccess As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function OpenPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" _
    Alias "OpenPrinterA" (ByVal pPrinterName As String, _
    phPrinter As Long, pDefault As PRINTER_DEFAULTS) As Long

Private Declare Function ClosePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" _
    (ByVal hPrinter As Long) As Long
```

You pass the Printer.DeviceName to this to get the handle.

```
Dim lret As Long
Dim pDef As PRINTER_DEFAULTS

lret = OpenPrinter(Printer.DeviceName, mhPrinter, pDef)
```

### The different statuses

There are a number of standard statuses that can be returned by the printer driver.

```
Public Enum Printer_Status
   PRINTER_STATUS_READY = &H0
   PRINTER_STATUS_PAUSED = &H1
   PRINTER_STATUS_ERROR = &H2
   PRINTER_STATUS_PENDING_DELETION = &H4
   PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_JAM = &H8
   PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_OUT = &H10
   PRINTER_STATUS_MANUAL_FEED = &H20
   PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_PROBLEM = &H40
   PRINTER_STATUS_OFFLINE = &H80
   PRINTER_STATUS_IO_ACTIVE = &H100
   PRINTER_STATUS_BUSY = &H200
   PRINTER_STATUS_PRINTING = &H400
   PRINTER_STATUS_OUTPUT_BIN_FULL = &H800
   PRINTER_STATUS_NOT_AVAILABLE = &H1000
   PRINTER_STATUS_WAITING = &H2000
   PRINTER_STATUS_PROCESSING = &H4000
   PRINTER_STATUS_INITIALIZING = &H8000
   PRINTER_STATUS_WARMING_UP = &H10000
   PRINTER_STATUS_TONER_LOW = &H20000
   PRINTER_STATUS_NO_TONER = &H40000
   PRINTER_STATUS_PAGE_PUNT = &H80000
   PRINTER_STATUS_USER_INTERVENTION = &H100000
   PRINTER_STATUS_OUT_OF_MEMORY = &H200000
   PRINTER_STATUS_DOOR_OPEN = &H400000
   PRINTER_STATUS_SERVER_UNKNOWN = &H800000
   PRINTER_STATUS_POWER_SAVE = &H1000000
End Enum
```